# In dotnet windows forms, how do I pause in a form without putting the form's thread to sleep?

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, sleep

Problem is I do not want to use Threading.Sleep(1000) because I need the thread to stay alive, just pause before executing the next line of code while disallowing the user to click anything on the form during the pause.  The simplest method I could think of was to open a timed self-closing dialog with an opacity of 0.  Any better way to get the same result?

Comment: I see you have a tag for multithreading. Are you trying to make the form wait for a thread to finish running in the background? If so, I suggest you take a look at the BackgroundWorker class. You can add handlers to the ProgressChanged and OnRunWorkerCompleted events, where you can set enabled to false when the progress changes to started and then true again when it is finished. Takes a bit to get it right, though. Might be best to go with Albin's answer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`Enabled = false;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx) and use a timer to set it to `true` later on.

Answer (score 0):

Set Enabled to false, and then some time later set it back to true.  You might do this on a separate thread.  Also consider changing the cursor to a wait cursor.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways :

- Disable the entire form, do your processing and enable it back again. (Use `Form.Enabled` property.)
- Show a modal dialog with no options to close it or move it (completely locked down) with a message something like 'Loading' or 'Processing', do your stuff and close it.